# cannot set specific tinymce textarea content from a function

Tags: tinymce

I have a page with multiple textareas that use TinyMCE to be able to display WYSIWYG content. This works fine but I need to set a specific textarea content from a function. I tried this approach...

```
    <script>
    function addText() {
        var html = "<b>hello world</b>";
        tinymce.get('#myFirstTextArea').setContent(html);
    }
</script>
```

But when I do that I get a "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setContent')" Error. What am I doing wrong here?

I use TinyMCE ver 6

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a timing issue in your JavaScript.  You cannot make a `get()` call until after TinyMCE is fully initialized.

TinyMCE has an event that gets called once the editor is fully initialized.  You can put this in your TinyMCE init.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init', function (e) {
         editor.setContent('<p>This is the content in TinyMCE!</p>');
      });
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: hmm, but the way I planned to use it was to fill the textarea with content on page load, and then give the option to fill the textarea with some default content if a user click a button (therefore the function). This suggestion will not allow that, right?

Comment: That suggestion will not but once TinyMCE is rendered and fully initialized the code you are trying to use should work just fine assuming you target a valid element.